# C# method to return two values from SQL Query, then get via jquery ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, ajax

**UPDATE:  This code now works!**  Between the answer below and my dev who emailed me from Romania, I got it sorted out.

```
 [Method]
    public object ConvDetails(string SENDERNAME, string VIEWURL)
    {

        {
            var list = new List<object>();

            new Command("select top 1 o.name [SENDERNAME], view_url [VIEWURL] from MESSAGE m join OPR_SECD o on UPDATED_BY = O.RECNUM where VIEW_URL like 'conversation.aspx%' and DELIVER_TO in (select OPR_INITIAL from OPR_SECD where recnum = @CURRENT_USER_ID) order by m.RECNUM desc")
                .AddInt("CURRENT_USER_ID", Common.UserID)
                .Each(R => list.Add(new
                {
                    VIEWURL = R.GetString("VIEWURL"),
                    SENDERNAME = R.GetString("SENDERNAME")
                }));

            return list;


        };
    }
```

Here's my ajax call to get the two strings from my method:

```
   convDetails: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + "pages/services/messages.ashx?method=convdetails",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            $("a.new-message-alert").attr("href", '' + data[0].VIEWURL);
            $("span#message-from").text("New Message From: " + data[0].SENDERNAME);
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

Between the response I got below and a few emails to our developer who's in Romania, I was able to piece it together.  I updated my code to what worked!  The having just data.VIEWURL didn't work.  I had to add the data[0].VIEWURL.  So, thanks Matt for that one.  Also, in my href i had to put in empty quotes or it would return NaN.  No idea why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that JavaScript isn't going to work whatever you do on the C# side. You're attempting synchronous processing of the result of an asynchronous call.

Your C# doesn't look far off, for some reason I totally failed to read it correctly first time around. I've never used a `.ashx` in quite that manner, I've always just spat out my response from ProcessRequest, but if your code is getting called then I just learned something new. I do, however, notice that you're returning a serialized list, but only processing one element.

You could use a more LINQy approach to eliminate the explicit list filling, though:

```
var list =
    from R in new Command("select top 1 o.name [SENDERNAME], view_url [VIEWURL] from MESSAGE m join OPR_SECD o on UPDATED_BY = O.RECNUM where VIEW_URL like 'conversation.aspx%' and DELIVER_TO in (select OPR_INITIAL from OPR_SECD where recnum = @CURRENT_USER_ID) order by m.RECNUM desc")
        .AddInt("CURRENT_USER_ID", Common.UserID)
    select new {
        VIEWURL = R.GetString("VIEWURL"),
        SENDERNAME = R.GetString("SENDERNAME") };
context.Response.Write(JsonConverter.SeralizeObject(list));
```

Your JS should look more like:

```
convDetails: function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + "pages/services/messages.ashx?method=convdetails",
        async: true,
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            $("a.new-message-alert").attr("href", data[0].VIEWURL);
            $("a.new-message-alert").text("New  message from: " + data[0].SENDERNAME);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.  How can I tell if I am using MVC or Web Forms?  I am usually only responsible for CSS/HTML stuff around here.  So, the whole ASP side of our app is a little foreign to me.

Comment: Well, this is in my page source.  Does this mean it's web forms?  `<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="
__VIEWSTATE" value="" />`

Comment: this exception is currently being thrown as well when the call is made... `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.\r\n`  There's no reason it should be converting varchar to numeric though.  Everything is strings.

Comment: ViewState is indicative that it's WebForms, yes. There are a few different ways to do AJAX callbacks with JSON in WebForms, the easiest is probably an `asmx`. The exception could be caused by your join criteria - `UPDATED_BY = RECNUM`, is updated_by a varchar?

Comment: ok i fixed the varchar error.  I had my @varible in quotes *facepalm*.  Now its throwing ths... `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n`

Comment: I presume that's on the JSON serialize? I can't see anywhere else that would be invoking reflection.

Comment: Between your help and my developer here we got it working! Thanks!